# Govt. organisation favouritism in its complaint handling

Tags: independence

I am analysing some data for a government organisation and trying to convince them that their complaint decisions are biased. I believe they favour certain organisations.

I have put together the following data, and done a chi-square test on it. The chi-square value is 25.34. I believe that the outcomes are not entirely independent. Is that the correct way? Additionally, is there any robust way to determine which organisation they are favouring?

```
Company      Upheld   Not Upheld

Comp.1               11       14
Comp.2              13        47
Comp.3              13        111
Comp.4               4        20
Comp.5               6        57
Comp.6              17        42
Comp.7               7        18
```

Comment: "I believe that the outcomes are not entirely independent."  This seems key, and you need to expand on it, as it's not clear what you have in mind.

Comment: Looking at Pearson residuals $(\text{observed} - \text{expected}) / \sqrt{\text{expected}}$ gives a scale on which to think about high and low counts.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to convince the organisation that the complaints are NOT decided on merit. But, they look at the name of the company and have a tendency to not make judgements against them.

Comment: @user238621 Which companies in specific? Do you have this information?

Comment: @user2974951 - anonymised company number is in the data set already. How do specific names matter?

Comment: @user238621 You said that they look at the name of a company first and then base their result on this. So which are these companies which you think are different, that is that they give different results to?

Comment: @user2974951 - from the data it seems company 3 and 5 don't get many complaints upheld against them.

Comment: @user238621 Ok so you don't know which companies these are, you merely suspect this to be true? That some companies get a different treatment based on name or whatever? Also, did a government organization vote on all companies? Can they vote multiple times for any given company?

Comment: @user2974951 let me re-explain. The public submits complaints against companies to this government organisation. This government organisation decides to either uphold the complaint or not uphold it. There's no question of voting. So I know the names of the companies.  Hope that helps.

Comment: The chi-square test does one thing only: quantify departure from a null expectation that the fractions upheld/not upheld are the same across companies. Nothing in the data or the analysis you've mentioned can quantify how far variations are genuine or deserved differences as compared with the result of bias in decision-making.

Comment: @NickCox - thanks. So first part of my question. The chi-square test is quantifying departure from a null expectation. Now I need to find a test to test bias in decision making?

Comment: The only way to do that is to find independent evidence for assessing what the rates would be if they were objective.  it's on all fours with me saying  to you that my measurement is 42. There is zero information in the measurement alone for you to judge any systematic error or bias in my procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing from the comments and adding some more information.

As @NickCox pointed out, all chi-square does is show that you can reject the null hypothesis that the proportion of complaints upheld is the same across companies. If this is all the data you have, there is little more that you can do.

You *could* add an assumption that complaints against each company are equally likely to be valid or justified. Depending on the particulars of the situation, that might be a reasonable assumption, a somewhat reasonable one, or a ludicrous one, but there is nothing in what you have posted that lets you show how reasonable it is.

If you have more data and, in particular, if you have data on how justified each complaint is, then there would be more you could do. You could model Pr(upheld) as a function of the company and the justification rating. The specifics of this model would depend on the nature of the data.

I could see some situations in which the same people are making complaints against multiple companies or the same company multiple times. If that is the case, you would have to account for that.

Comment: Hi there - thanks for everyone's help. To confirm:  1. The data that I have available does reject the null hypothesis (and the proportion of complaints upheld is NOT the same across companies).  2. If we assume that the complaints should be equally likely to be upheld or not. How would we proceed?

Comment: @user238621 claiming that complaints should be equally likely to be upheld among all organizations is an extremely strong assumption and contrary to many people's experience. Some organizations are simply less trustworthy than others. Should you try to convince a government body that it is showing favoritism based solely on results of a chi-square test, you would (rightly) not get very far. The answer is not in the statistical test per se but in the proper application of statistical and experimental design principles, as outlined in this answer.

Comment: If you want to make this assumption, you should assemble evidence for it. A LOT of evidence.  You are making a serious accusation - one that might even be criminal. If you base it just on "I think this is the case" you will be laughed at.

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for everyone's input. I have no intention of saying anything beyond the chi-square and limit it to what it indicates. Just a bit of context all these companies are regulated by the countries' regulator. Additionally, this particular govt. organisation is already under the microscope for various issues.